# How to check the deliverability of my outgoing email (spam, dkim, dmarc, spf)

Tags: email, server, spam-prevention, dkim

The project I'm working on is a newsletter builder, and I'm on its final steps. Now I need to verify spf dkim and dmark (which I don't know what they mean or how they work). Then I also need to check if my email is considered as spam or if any of the news contains spam (separately). I tried to read the documentation of 2 great spamcheckers (spamassassin and rspamd) and I couldn't understand anything about how they are supposed to be integrated on my project. I think all my problems are due to my lack of knowledge related to emails/email servers and stuff related. I'd really appreciate if someone could enlight me about what are the steps that I need to do, if I really need to setup an email server to test this out and how to do it etc. etc. I'm really in the dark here. I know the enterprise I'm doing this work for already was sending emails from their domain but I don't think they gave me access to that.

Answer (score 0):

The following link may be useful to you, it's a document of iRedMail (an open source mail server solution):
https://docs.iredmail.org/setup.dns.html
You don't need to know what iRedMail is, just check the introduction of each dns record.
For me, these introductions are enough, if you want a more detailed introduction, wikipedia and official website may be more useful

For checking spam status and dns records such as spf, dkim, etc., setting spamassassin or rspamd by yourself may be complicated, but there are many free services available.
I often use the following (I have my own mail server, so I sometimes use these services for testing):
https://www.mail-tester.com/
https://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: Can we talk through discord or something, so I can be more specific? I think the enterprise i'm working to already has an email server, I just need to know If I actually need it and should ask them access to it. It's not like i want to set up a new email server if they already have a domain and were sending newsletters from it beforemy project. Thanks anyway, i'll see what I can do with the second part of your answer.